# Spring 3.2 - Unable To Resolve View Name After Switching To JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, dispatcher

I just converted all of my xml config files to JavaConfig using Spring MVC 3.2.3 and Spring Security 3.2.1.  I ran into some issues where entities that had members annotated with @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) still weren't being fetched (a problem I didn't have with my XML config) and I had to add the @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) annotation.  I'm still having problems retrieving data from my controllers, however.

Many of my requests get fully processed by the back-end, but when they're returned from my controller method, I get the error "HTTP Status 500 - Could not resolve view with name 'xxx' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'".  The problem is, I only have 3 views:  login, index, and admin.  The index page is a single page site that does a lot of AJAX calls to controllers, most of which unmarshal JSON requests to DTOs using @RequestBody, and all of which write the response directly with @ResponseBody and get converted to JSON using Jackson.  This has always worked in the past -- the controller methods should literally just be REST endpoints, but now, the dispatcher servlet wants to associate a view with almost all of my requests, but not all.  I'm not sure how to tell the view resolver or dispatcher servlet to only treat index, admin, and login as views, and just treat everything else as a simple REST request.  Any help would be appreciated!  Here is my config:

Root Config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "x.configuration", excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = RootConfig.class))
public class RootConfig {}
```

SecurityInitializer:

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {}
```

WebApp Initializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringMvcConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{
            "/rest/*",
            "/index.html",
            "/login.html",
            "/admin.html",
            "/index/*",
            "/login/*",
            "/admin/*"
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter openEntityManagerInViewFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        openEntityManagerInViewFilter.setBeanName("openEntityManagerInViewFilter");       
        openEntityManagerInViewFilter.setPersistenceUnitName("HSQL");
        return new javax.servlet.Filter[]{openEntityManagerInViewFilter};
    }
}
```

Spring MVC config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
{@ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=Controller.class)})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "x.clients")
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"login", "index", "admin"});
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping getDefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping() {
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setAlwaysUseFullPath(true);
        handlerMapping.setDetectHandlersInAncestorContexts(true);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(getMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }


    @Bean 
    public JacksonAnnotationIntrospector getJacksonAnnotationIntrospector(){
        return new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(getJacksonAnnotationIntrospector());
        mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter getMappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter(){
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(getObjectMapper());

        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultConversionService getDefaultConversionService(){
        return new DefaultConversionService();
    }
}
```

Spring Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationProvider rememberMeAuthenticationProvider = getRememberMeAuthenticationProvider();
        TokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedRememberMeServices = getTokenBasedRememberMeServices();

        List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>(2);
        authenticationProviders.add(rememberMeAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationProviders.add(customAuthenticationProvider);
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = getAuthenticationManager(authenticationProviders);

        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .addFilter(new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, tokenBasedRememberMeServices))
                .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(tokenBasedRememberMeServices)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/login", "/processLogin").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/index.jsp", "/index.html", "/index").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin", "/admin.html", "/admin.jsp").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/processLogin").loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager getAuthenticationManager(List<AuthenticationProvider> authenticationProviders) {
        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProviders);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenBasedRememberMeServices getTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        return new TokenBasedRememberMeServices("testKey", userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider getRememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider("testKey");
    }

    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

All of my controller methods are accessed via the URL pattern /rest//.

The following controller simply returns a list of enumerated items and works fine:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/swterms")
public class SwTermsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSensorTypes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getSensorTypes() {
        List<String> sensorTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (SensorTypes sensorType : SensorTypes.values()){
            sensorTypes.add(sensorType.getURI());
        }
        return sensorTypes;
    }
}
```

This controller returns a list of map layers.  I can step through in debug mode and everything is built fine, but it produces the 500 error:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class MapLayerController {

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name="mapLayers") private List<OpenLayersMapLayer> mapLayers;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getLayerData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map getMapLayers() {
        Map model = new HashMap();
        model.put("layers", this.mapLayers);
        return model;
    }   
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
 00:12:21,034 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /rest/map/getLayerData at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    00:12:21,034 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/logout'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/js/**'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/css/**'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/img/**'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/login'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/processlogin'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/index.jsp'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/index.html'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/index'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/admin'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/admin.html'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/admin.jsp'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : '/rest/map/getlayerdata'; against '/js/saic/jswe/admin/**'
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] - Public object - authentication not attempted
    00:12:21,035 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] - /rest/map/getLayerData reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
    00:12:21,041 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/swtc/rest/map/getLayerData]
    00:12:21,041 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Looking up handler method for path /map/getLayerData
    00:12:21,042 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.ui.ModelMap x.clients.controllers.MapLayerController.getMapLayers(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]
    00:12:21,042 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mapLayerController'
    00:12:21,042 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Last-Modified value for [/swtc/rest/map/getLayerData] is: -1
    00:12:44,844 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - Could not complete request
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'map/getLayerData' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    00:12:44,902 (http-bio-8084-exec-77) DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove this line:

```
viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"login", "index", "admin"});
```

This is causing the viewResolver to ignore everything not in ["login","index","admin"]

Taken from the documentation:

> setViewNames
>
> **public void setViewNames(String[] viewNames)** Set the view names (or
>   name patterns) that can be handled by this ViewResolver. View names
>   can contain simple wildcards such that 'my*', '*Report' and '*Repo*'
>   will all match the view name 'myReport'.

Comment: I'll try again, but I actually added that line in hopes it would help solve the original problem -- thinking maybe if I specifically told it what the views were it wouldn't treat the other requests like a jerk :)

Comment: I understand. But, the view that fails is not in this array, it's "map/getLayerData", so either remove the line or add this view to the array of setViewNames.

Comment: Well you made a liar out of me!  That worked!  Now I just have one AJAX call giving me a 404 not found, even though I'm stepping through the method in debug mode and it's definitely getting called and returning a value....  Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm.. this is what it says in the log... Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/alerting/getSubscriptionCount.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'alerting/getSubscriptionCount'.  Again, this isn't a view and there is no jsp... wonder why this one is having a problem.

Comment: It appears now that simply returning the ModelMap causes it to think it's a view.  I just need to convert all of my ModelMaps to regular Maps.